# InstallTrigger.install Equivalent in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extension

In firefox InstallTrigger.install  is used to download xpi file. What is used to download the crx file in chrome browser. The download should start without the user click.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Simply change the location of your window, use `window.location.href = "http://.../extension.crx";`.</strike>

**Edit**: The answer above is outdated, Chrome no longer requires installing extensions from any website other than Chrome WebStore.

There is a supported [inline installation flow](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation) that allows you to trigger installation for your extension from your website. This requires your website to be verified and associated with the extension in the Chrome Web Store. Then you can add a `<link rel="chrome-webstore-item">` tag to the page pointing to your extension in Chrome Web Store and a call to `chrome.webstore.install()` will start installation.